# Rust отслеживание запуска/открытие программ

Tags: rust

Я начал изучать rust и хотел бы сделать программу которая будет отслеживать запуск определённых программ(для проверки: браузер chrome). Когда пользователь запустит браузер chrome, то моя программа приостановит процесс и запросит у пользователя пароль на запуск браузера. Возможно такое сделать?

Буду благодарен всем!